# How to make the merge query to do insert once in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `merge` query, in which when the merge search condition is not matched the insert position id column we are generating uniquely based on the table name. For that we use a separate function for generation.

But the select statement in the merge query is executing once. So the same id is getting inserted in the table.

```
 declare @tenantid uniqueidentifier, 
 @upid uniqueidentifier,
 @endDate datetime ,
 @pid nvarchar(14)

declare @emp table
(
    Action nvarchar(50),
    PositionId nvarchar(14),
    ReferenceId nvarchar(14)
)

set @endDate = '9999-12-31 00:00:00.000'
set @upid = 'B00D76D1-E0EF-4614-8F2C-77E01D37BFE8'
set @tenantid= 'CEA19256-7C40-40A2-A7A9-0DD5122904D6'

insert into @emp
select Action,PositionId, ReferenceId
from
(
merge hr.Position as position 
using (select PositionId,CreatedBy,TenantId from upl.Employee where UploadId= @upid   and TenantId = @TenantId ) as uplEmpl
on position.ReferenceId= uplEmpl.PositionId and position.TenantId= uplEmpl.TenantId
when matched 
  then update set position.LastUpdatedBy =  uplEmpl.CreatedBy,position.LastUpdatedDate= GetDate()
when not matched then
 insert   (PositionId,ReferenceId,StartDate,EndDate,CreatedBy,CreatedDate,LastUpdatedBy,LastUpdatedDa  te,TenantId)
  values((select   mst.getNextNumber('Position',null,null,@TenantId)),uplEmpl.PositionId,GetDate(),@endDate,up      lEmpl.CreatedBy,GetDate(),uplEmpl.CreatedBy,GetDate(),@tenantid)
  output $action,Inserted.PositionId,Inserted.ReferenceId)
  as changes(Action,PositionId,ReferenceId)

select * from @emp
```

[image: Blockquote]

Can anyone suggest how to make the function to execute every time when we call the insert statement in merge query

Comment: Is it not that that you are using the same predicate each time against the select.  "Where uploadId = @upId and TenantID = @TenantId"

Comment: That is to get the list of employee values from the upl.Employee based on the upload id and tenant id since the table may have all the list of uploaded values. The exact issue is with the insert has a select statement , i think the merge is basically executing on a single scan not on every insert.

Comment: I think you'll need to post the body of mst.getNextNumber on here so people will be able to help you.

Comment: Side note - technically there isn't such a thing as an "end-date", there's just a start date for something else.  This is closely bound to [safely querying continuous types, like date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)  Therefore, if you have no new state (no new start date), the date should be `null`.  Trying to use hival dates is problematic, and they never stay in sync (having worked on a system that _tried_...)

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming the following order of events:

1. Generate ID
2. Insert
3. Generate ID
4. Insert
5. ...

But the SQL Standard says that first all values to write a calculated, then all writes are made:

1. Generate ID
2. Generate ID
3. ...
4. Insert
5. Insert
6. ...

Combined with the fact that functions cannot change data you cannot use this approach. Your ID generator function can only ever return the same value because it cannot record that a certain ID has been used. No matter what `getNextNumber` contains, it is not allowed to write.

Honestly, I'm a little out of good ideas here. Here is one that would work, though:

Insert dummy IDs, output the changes into a table variable and after the `MERGE` statement loop through that table to `UPDATE` the dummy values to use real values. Here, you can invoke side-effecting procedures. You can't do that as part of the `MERGE`.

Or, abandon `MERGE` and use a loop/cursor to do the writes. You can still perform most work as part of the cursor query and only apply the writes in a loop. A `MERGE` translates to a full outer join (in your case a left join is enough). You'd need to write that up yourself.

Comment: In such case how about the performance in the cursor/loop. I have to merge more than a million record in single shot. I think cursor gives performance lag when compared to merge . Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Lokesh for 1m records you would indeed want a set-based operation but as I showed you cannot write to the database as part of a query except for what the respective DML statement explicitly provides. Perform as much work as possible as part of the cursor query. Then the loop will only need to execute a trivial DML statement per item. However, maybe you can calculate the PositionId using ROW_NUMBER? Something like: PositionId = MaximimPreviousPositionId + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...).

Comment: Another thing that would not work with the current approach is that the order in which the rows are written is not specified with SQL Server. You could get wildly different orders.